# PropertyInfo GetValue() Object does not match target type

Tags: c#, types

I want to read value of a T type

```
  public virtual ActionResult Edit(TEditDTO editedDTO)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(editedDTO);
        var t = editedDTO.GetType();
        var prop = t.GetProperty("Id") ;
        var Id = prop.GetValue(t); // get exception
     }
```

but get

> Object does not match target type

Comment: How is the `Id` property defined?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should pass the instance of `TEditDTO` to `GetValue` method not the type instance.

```
var Id = prop.GetValue(editedDTO);
```

Comment: this generates a compiler error since the second argument is required.

Comment: @flo_badea no it doesn't. otherwise the OP's code wouldn't even compile

Comment: @flo_badea, single parameter it only works for .net 4.5, that's why I chose two parameter for backward compatibility reason

Comment: Works like a champ.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
var Id = prop.GetValue(editedDTO, null);
```

Comment: @Mohammadreza, same exception? what's the error with this code?

Answer (score 4):

the PropertyInfo.GetValue method accepts as the first argument an instance of the type for which you want to read the value. if using an indexer you also need to specify an additional array argument to GetValue. since both arguments are required you need to pass null for the second one when reading a normal property.
in your example you're passing a Type instance instead of a TEditDTO instance. use the code below.

```
var Id = prop.GetValue(editedDTO, null);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public virtual ActionResult Edit(TEditDTO editedDTO)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(editedDTO); 
    PropertyInfo prop = typeof(editedDTO).GetProperty("Id") ;
    Object Id = prop.GetValue(editedDTO); 
}
```